# How to produce LocationRequest resolution dialog and catch onActivityResult callback in Service

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

So im using the `FusedLocationApi` to get the users location. Im also using the `LocationRequest` object to check if a location source is available and if not, ask the user for permission to turn on GPS(WiFi seems not to work on Lollipop devices). Now when the user clicks yes(or no), `onActivityResult` is called. My problem is, i have a `Service` that does nothing but tracks the users location, but i cannot use the `LocationRequest` object for resolution in the `Service`(which is precisely what i need) because `Service` doesnt have an `onActivityResult` method. Any tips on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious answer was to launch this dialog in the `Activity` before starting the `Service`, then calling `startService()` in `onAcivityResult`, or if no resolution is required.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for it in the activity, you cant request such things from inside an service indeed. A service is a background component without an GUI.